# "Dominating" a function (to differentiate under integral sign)

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Let $f\left(x,t\right)$ given for $\left(x,t\right) \in \left(\mathbb{R}^{+}\right)^2$ by
$$
f\left(x,t\right)=\frac{x\sin\left(xt\right)}{1+x^2}
$$
Is there a way to show that it exists $\varphi$ so that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left|\varphi\left(v\right)\right|\text{d}v<+\infty$ and
$$
\left|f\left(x,t\right) \right| \leq \varphi\left(x\right)
$$
The thing is I think that
$$
\left|f\left(x,t\right)\right| \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{\sin\left(xt\right)}{x}
$$
which is surely semi-convergent hence it is not easy for me ...
I've tried then to work on a compact set $K=\left[a,b\right] \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ but I dont succeed in finding such a $\varphi$ even in this case !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(xt)}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2\sin(xt)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+x^2-1)\sin(xt)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(xt)}{x}\,dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(xt)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac\pi2\text{sgn}(t) -\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(xt)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

So, the original integral converges, but it does not converge absolutely ($\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\sin(xt)}{x}\right|\,dx=\infty$ for $t\ne 0$).

Interestingly, the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ does converge absolutely.

---

> **EDITED TO ADDRESS A COMMENT LEFT BY THE OP:**

Note that $\int_0^\infty \frac{-x\sin(xt)}{1+x^2}\,dx$ converges uniformly for $|t|>\delta>0$.  Hence, we have

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{-x\sin(xt)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

for all $|t|\ge \delta>0$.

Comment: Yeah i was stuck there. In fact i wanted to differentiate under integral sign for $\displaystyle (x,t) \mapsto \frac{\cos\left(xt\right)}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: With the equality $(1)$, you can differentiate under the integral of the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.  And you can justify $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+x^2}=\int_0^\infty \frac{-x\sin(xt)}{1+x^2}\,dx$ for $|t|>\delta>0$ owing to the uniform convergence of the differentiated integrand.

Comment: Yes but that is not this integral that i want to differentiate but the one i mentioned just one comment before, with a $\cos$ :/ Or may i find such a function $\varphi$ using $(1)$ ? I may be confused by the term " uniform convergence " in english for an integral.

Comment: You can justify $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+x^2}=\int_0^\infty \frac{-x\sin(xt)}{1+x^2}\,dx$ for $|t|>\delta>0$ owing to the uniform convergence of the differentiated integrand.

Comment: Mmh i may be confused with " uniform convergence " ( maybe due to my french native language ) what does it mean ? Same as a sequence convergence uniformly ?

Comment: Atmos, [See This](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, is that obvious that there's uniforem convergence ?